# How to use curly braces of the "newcomputermodern" font with newtx package

Tags: newtxmath

My question is the following. I want to use the `{` and `}` **math braces** of the `newcomputermodern` package while using the `newtxmath` package. Can this be done. If yes please help me with the commands.

I am using Texlive distribution with ubuntu.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{extarticle}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
\begin{document}
$$\left\{\frac{1}{x}\right\}$$
\end{document}
```

This command gives me the newtxmath braces, whereas i want the braces to be of the `newcomputermodern` font.

Comment: Please provide a minimal compilable document demonstrating what you want to do and indicating which engine you're using. Do you want to use these in maths or text? Sizes? `fontspec`?

Comment: @cfr : I have edited my question with whatever minimal knowledge i poses. Hope this clarifies.

Comment: It's not newcomputermodern, but the `cmbraces` option of newtxmath gives the Computer Modern braces

Comment: @mbert : My question though is how to use braces of "newcomputermodern" into another package. It might not necessarily be `newtxmath` it can be any other package.

Comment: Do you really want the newcomputermodern braces? I am sure they would be similar to the other computer modern clones, unless you look in really close.

Comment: newcomputermodern is only available as opentype so not for pdflatex, if you are using pdflatex do you want computer modern  baces, that is the default if no package is used?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle : Yes, i want `newcomputermodern` braces especially because it appears HEAVIER and suits newtx or any other heavy font very well.

Comment: @ApoorvPotnis : Yes, Apoorv i want `newcomputermodern` braces because they appear heavier than the standard computer modern :) :)

Comment: Perhaps it would be better then to switch to lualatex or xelatex. (unless you are forced with pdflatex) Then you can use Times clones such as TeX Gyre Termes and XITS. newtxmath takes its symbols from termes, if I recall correctly. You can easily define a new math font for newcomputermodern in with unicode-math (in lua/xelatex) and use its symbols. You can take a look at stix2 fonts as well for some amount of times compatibility.

Comment: if you are using pdftex you can't (without a lot of effort) use opentype math fonts. pdftex is an 8 bit system so all fonts have at most 256 characters, opentype fonts have a few thousand characters......

Comment: @ApoorvPotnis : Fine i am ok with `xelatex`

Comment: You can use the `range` option of `\setmathfont` from unicode-math, but I don't think the latter is compatible with newtxmath

Comment: If you find a symbol you like in a traditional font (e.g. type 1 or truetype with LaTeX support), you could use https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14386/importing-a-single-symbol-from-a-different-font?noredirect=1&lq=1.

Comment: @cfr I am kind of confused. It would be better to have the complete commands.

Comment: @C.S. You'd have to use something from a traditional font for the solution I linked to work, so there aren't any commands to use with New Computer Modern, since it's not available in that format (as far as I know).